# simpleXMLElement find node

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

i have the following structure in an xml-element:

```
<assets>

    <icon id="1" type="grave" x="586" y="477">
        <text short="hello world" tooltip="" tteng=" "/>
    </icon>

</assets>
```

Now, using `PHP`, i try to find this specific `node` with `xpath`. I have to find this node by the short-value in the `<text>` snippet.

So, i need to get the parent of

```
<text="hello world" ... >
```

I was looking on `php.net`, but it didn't helped me that much.

What i tried is this:

```
$node = $xml->xpath('//text="hello world"');
```

but that didn't do the trick.

Regarding to the info from **marc-b** i added the following to my function:

```
public static function loadValuesFromNode($fileName, $name) {

    var_dump($name); // echoes "hello world"

    $xml = simplexml_load_file(self::$xmlDir . "/" . $fileName); // correct path, already tested
    $node = $xml->xpath('//text[@short="'.$name.'"]');

    var_dump($node); // empty -> (array(0) { }

}
```

If i change the xpath to:

```
'[@short="'.$name.'"'] (so without the text-thingy)
```

it returns "false";

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test an attribute's contents, you need

```
//node[@attribute="value"]
```

so

```
//text[@short="hello world"]
```

Comment: This returns and empty value :/ i edited my post, if you want to have a look. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: nvm, i'm dumb, forgot the // - Thank you :)